# How to print px to % in after sass variable?

Tags: css, loops, sass

I want print px to % how it possible ? i am create margin classes using loop px is working fine but when i set % than not working like margin-#{$side}: #{$space}%; any solution. i want out-put in %. Thanks in adavance

```css
$spaceamounts: (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 100);
$top: (top);

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
    @each $side in $top {
        .margin-#{$side}-#{$space} {
            margin-#{$side}: #{$space}px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this to achieve desired result [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

```
$spaceamounts: (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 100);
$top: (top);

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
    @each $side in $top {
        .margin-#{$side}-#{$space} {
            margin-#{$side}: #{$space}+'%';
        }
    }
}
```

Edit - when using node-sass using gulp use unquote

```
$spaceamounts: (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 100);
$top: (top);
@each $space in $spaceamounts { 
    @each $side in $top { 
         .margin-#{$side}-#{$space} { 
              margin-#{$side}: unquote(#{$space})+'%'; 
           } 
      }
}
```

Comment: It compiles to correct code , I tried compiling online. , so are you getting compilation error ?

Comment: @DharmeshVekariya the code works fine, try it here and see: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: Ok , i tried using gulp and it doesnot compile , can you try with the below code 
`$spaceamounts: (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 100);
$top: (top);

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
    @each $side in $top {
        .margin-#{$side}-#{$space} {
            margin-#{$side}: unquote(#{$space})+'%';
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I hope below code will be helpful for you

```
$spaceamounts: (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 100);
$top: (top);
$percent: ("%");

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
    @each $side in $top {
        .margin-#{$side}-#{$space} {
            margin-#{$side}: #{$space}#{$percent};
        }
    }
}
```

OR you can use `unquote("%")` like

```
@each $space in $spaceamounts {
    @each $side in $top {
        .margin-#{$side}-#{$space} {
            margin-#{$side}: #{$space}unquote("%");
        }
    }
}
```